# chown on items in nfs mount get wrong user

Tags: nfs

I have an nfs share mounted on my linux box.  If users create files or directories, everything works fine and the newly created item is owned by that user.  However if root goes in and does a chown on an item, it ends up being owned by 32547.  Something similar happens with groups, it ends up as 1310644168. [Edit: I just noticed the number changes based on every time I restart nfs on the server.  So if I restart nfs and remount it on the client and then I do a chgrp test1 dir2, it ends up with group 28772371144]

On the server hosting the share, idmapd uses Method = static.  The options in /etc/exports are rw,insecure,sync,no_all_squash,no_root_squash.

On the box that has it mounted, fstab has the following options: bg,intr,soft,timeo=5,retrans=5,actimeo=10,retry=5

What do I need to do to allow root to change the owner or group of items in the share?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found this item: https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7014266

Basically to make it work on the RHEL server I had to do:

```
 echo 1 > /sys/module/nfsd/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping
```

Now everything just works.